# #if DEBUG sempre é executado, mesmo em modo release

Tags: c#, .net, preprocessador

Estou tentando usar a diretiva `#if` para que determinado método seja executado somente depois de publicado (em modo release).

O código é algo como

```
#if !DEBUG
    AlgumMetodo();
#endif
```

Eu também já tentei adicionar o `ConditionalAttribute` na assinatura do método

```
[Conditional("RELEASE")]
private void AlgumMetodo() { ... }
```

O problema é que das duas formas o método **nunca** é executado, não importa se estiver em modo *release* ou *debug*.

Já conferi nas propriedades do projeto, na aba *build*. Na configuração *release* o checkbox `define DEBUG constant` está desmarcado e na configuração *debug* ele está marcado.

Tem mais alguma configuração que eu possa verificar ou algo que eu esteja fazendo errado?

Comment: Experimenta colocar um `#define RELEASE` no começo deste código pra ver se muda alguma coisa, pelo menos vamos saber melhor onde está o problema. Eu nunca usei isto, mas eu acho que não se usa assim. Eu acho que se é para ser usado no *release*, então deixe normal, só bloqueie o que só deve ser usado em *debug mode*.

Comment: Eu preciso justamente do contrário. Preciso que o método não execute se estiver em debug. De qualquer forma eu consegui resolver definindo `RELEASE` nas configurações de build do projeto.

Comment: É um pouco estranho isso, acho que está conceituando errado. Acho que o recursos não foi criado para fazer isto. Ainda assim precisa fazer testes para descobri onde é o problema, conforme eu falei.

Comment: Você está `Publicando` seu app ou pegando o conteúdo da pasta bin? lembre-se que o conteúdo da pasta bin sempre vai rodar em modo `Debug` visto que ele sempre será compilado neste formato para você proceder com os testes.

Comment: O conteúdo da pasta `bin/Release` é gerado pelo modo release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em vez de recorrer a inversão de lógica (`if !DEBUG`), defina o seu próprio símbolo nas configurações que dele necessitam.

Para o fazer aceda as propriedades do projecto. Nas propriedades do projecto clique na aba *Build*. Dentro da aba, selecione a configuração que quer alterar (neste caso *Release*) e na caixa *Conditional compilation symbols* escreva `RELEASE`. Veja a seguinte imagem com o resultado final.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o símbolo definido, pode fazer o seguinte no código:

```
public void oMeuMetodo()
{

#if RELEASE

 // o meu codigo que so vai ser executado nas configurações que tenham o simbolo RELEASE definido

#endif

}
```

Nota:

O campo aceita valores separados por virgulas, portanto se precisar de definir mais símbolos pode fazer `RELEASE, METRICS, ETC` e usa-los como demonstrado em cima.

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei.