# Para que servem e quando usar as diretivas do preprocessador?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, preprocessador

A algum tempo eu tinha visto o uso de `#define` no C#. Hoje eu procurei sobre isso e achei sua documentação [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/), mas não respondeu a todas as minhas duvidas.

Exemplo de código com diretivas de preprocessador:

```
#define DEBUG  

#if DEBUG  
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");  
#endif
```

Diante disso, minhas duvidas são:

- Para que servem as diretivas de preprocessador?
- Quando eu devo usar as diretivas de preprocessador?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Servem para um monte de coisas, cada uma serve para algo diferente. Servem para mudar o comportamento do compilador em determinado trecho.

Deve usar sempre que tiver necessidade de mudar a compilação. Quase nunca existe em códigos normais. De fato elas devem ser evitadas até que não tenha solução melhor. E C# tem poucas.

Na verdade tem a diretiva `#region` que não muda a compilação e ajuda a organização no IDE, e [muitos consideram isso um erro da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82413/101).

Passar todas é uma pergunta muito ampla. Tem algumas perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Entendendo diretiva #line](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155730/101)
- [O que é #pragma c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210692/101)

O `#if` determina se o código dentro dele será compilado ou ignorado. Isto é decidido se uma variável de compilação, que nada tem a ver com as variáveis do código, existe. Em geral essas variáveis são definidas como argumento no compilador.

Em C# é raro precisar criar uma variável com `#define`, em alguns casos outro pedaço pode gerar condicionalmente. Isso era muito usado em C porque a linguagem não era poderosa e precisava quase de outra linguagem para para ajudar criar o que era desejado. Mesmo hoje C precisa menos disso, e C++ pode eliminar quase por completo.

No exemplo mostrado o código será compilado porque a variável foi criada logo acima, o que nem faz sentido em código real.

Então aí é para compilar trechos condicionalmente. Na verdade, tem [outras formas de resolver o mesmo para depurar código que não precisa da diretiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110284/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).